# Can anyone explain why this JavaScript wont run

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, web-applications

Im not very good wit JS and I just dont get why this wont work!
The code uses jquery to apply the pulsate efect to one of my divs and run forever unless I stop it with another function, but I cannot figure our why my first piece of code wont run!

```
function animate(var x){
    // Do pulsate animation
    $(x).effect("pulsate", { times:4 }, 5000);
    // set timeout and recall after 10secs
    setTimeout(animate, 10000);
}
  $(document).ready(animate("#mydiv"));
```

Only way to get it working is for me to do this

```
function animate(){
    // Do pulsate animation
    $("#mydiv").effect("pulsate", { times:4 }, 5000);
    // set timeout and recall after 10secs
    setTimeout(animate, 10000);
}
  $(document).ready(animate);
```

*Note that in the first snippet the code uses variables to be more useful and the second piece has the selectors name hardcoded*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

omit the var:

```
function animate(x){
```

modify your event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   animate("#mydiv");
});
```

You need to hand over a function reference (either `animate` or `function(){}`), not run the code right away which you are doing if you pass `animate()`.

Now to not lose the reference to your `x` you have to modify the animate call in the timeout too:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        animate(x);
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: Oooooooh so I need to pass a reference always then. Cool thx a lot!

Comment: @Termiux sure, this is a callback. If you do not pass it ad reference, you are executing your callback right away and pass the returnvalue of it to the DOMready.

Comment: @Christoph: Would `$(document).ready(animate.bind(this, "#mydiv"));` work?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl No, that sets the value of `this` in the `animate` function. So technically, it could work if the function started using `this` instead of `x`.

Comment: @Ian: Sorry, I noticed that and updated the comment to pass `this, argument` instead. Would that work?

Comment: @FrançoisWahl sure, if you'd use `this` inside instead of x. Remember, `bind` sets the scope, not the parameters.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Oops, sorry, not sure if I missed that. But yeah, technically that would work too. It's unnecessary to set `this`, but doesn't hurt

Comment: @Christoph: Sorry about the edit. I thought I fixed it before anyone saw it.. :) +1 on answer though as using the `document.ready(function(){})` is propably preferred and better practice alright.

Comment: @Termiux don't forget to accept Ian's or my answer if this solved your problem to mark your issue as solved. Cheers.

Comment: Simply changing the `document.ready` problem won't fix everything. The `setTimeout(animate, 10000);` won't provide the reference to `x` anymore...so the element won't animate after first time calling `animate`

Comment: Regarding best practices for `$(document).ready(function() { });` it is definitely idiomatic for jQuery to write it either that way, or with the shorthand `$(function() { });`. [Read more in the API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: @Ian missed that one. Fixing in the head is good, testing is better;)

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `var` in your function declaration. Just use:

```
function animate(x){
```

Also, you probably want something like this for your first example:

```
function animate(x){
    return function () {
        function animateInner() {
            $(x).effect("pulsate", { times:4 }, 5000);
            setTimeout(animateInner, 10000);
        }
        animateInner();
    };
}
$(document).ready(animate("#mydiv"));
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XHKbC/

Otherwise, the original `animate("#mydiv")` call executes immediately (and `$(x)` probably won't find anything since the DOM isn't ready yet). `$(document).ready()` expects a reference to a function. You called a function instead. But that's all a little overkill. Just use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    animate("#mydiv");
});
```

but you'll have to change your function so the `setTimeout` passes the value of `x` as well:

```
function animate(x){
    // Do pulsate animation
    $(x).effect("pulsate", { times:4 }, 5000);
    // set timeout and recall after 10secs
    setTimeout(function () {
        animate(x);
    }, 10000);
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XHKbC/2/

Although it's a little more code/complex, my first example doesn't suffer the problem in my second (having to pass `x` in the `setTimeout`) by using a closure.

**UPDATE:**

Being shown how you are using this code, I'd set it up like this:

```
function Animater(target) {
    var self = this;
    var animateTO;
    var animateElement = target;

    function animate() {
        animateElement.effect("pulsate", { times:4 }, 5000);
        animateTO = setTimeout(animate, 10000);
    }

    self.start = function () {
        animate();
    };

    self.stop = function () {
        animateElement.finish();
        clearTimeout(animateTO);
    };
}
```

And create a new one like:

```
var mydivAnimater = new Animater($("#mydiv"));
```

You can then call `.start()` and `.stop()` on it, and you create any number of these `Animater` objects on different elements as you want.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/K7bQC/3/

Comment: Hehe, you wanna beat me hard, do you? ^_^

Comment: @Christoph Haha I'm not trying to go against you. The first thing I noticed was the `var`, so I posted. Then I realized the function was messy in the first place, so I tried to refactor, and did too much, so I just wanted to include the options I thought of :)

Comment: +1 great answer. Explanations and Demos are always usefull to future users looking for similar solutions.

Comment: @Ian can u maybe show how to stop the animation?. I've been tyring with this http://jsfiddle.net/W7eES/ (based on ur fiddle) but it wont stop :S

Comment: @Termiux I think the problem was because you weren't including the "stop"'s `click` handler in `$(document).ready`. Anyways, I think you're doing a little too much to "stop" it. Either way, I updated my answer with how I would structure it and a demo. Let me know if you're still having any trouble

Comment: @Ian yeah it seems the problem was as u said, the click handler being assigned outside `$(document).ready`. Anyways thx for the code, it had one issue (line 6 animate has not params) I corrected it http://jsfiddle.net/K7bQC/2/ Thx a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to type **var** when specifying a function parameter.